# How to retrieve data from AWS API Gateway and display it in static website hosted on S3?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to make an ajax request to AWS API Gateway in order to display some information contained in a json. The goal is to display a webpage, when the user loads the webpage, an ajax request is made to API Gateway, which runs a lambda function that retrieves some data from DynamoDB. Something like this: Website loaded -> API Gateway is called -> lambda function is executed -> data is retrieved from DDB -> data is returned to website html and displayed. The data that is being passed around is just a JSON format, and it contains a few entries but the one I care about is just an int, `"int" : "1"`.

Below is HTML format for the website, it is hosted in AWS S3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> This number was generated by the ESP32 </h1>

        <div id="entries">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var API_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-location-x.amazonaws.com/prod/gateway';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({

                    url: API_URL,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(data){
                        $('#entries').html('');
                        $('#entries').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and the lambda function code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-location-x' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let tableToRead = {
    TableName: 'dataStore',
    Limit: 10
  };

  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
    // other headers 
  }

  try {
    const data = docClient.scan(tableToRead).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: headers
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: error.message,
      headers: headers
    }
  }
};
```

At the moment, if I test the lambda function (in the lambda dashboard) it returns a JSON format but the body section is empty, it's just `{ }`. I need the data returned to contain the header and also the content from DynamoDB. Return looks like this:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{}",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

But it should look like this:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{
    "Items": [
    {
      "Payload": {
        "int": 6
      },
      "Row": "0",
      "PositionInRow": "0"
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1,
  "ScannedCount": 1
  }",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

Or something similar...The data from the DB is irrelevant, I just need the "int" parameter. That's just the issue I'm having with the lambda, I also need to know how to get that info to the HTML file. At the moment, when I run the website, it just displays `[object Object]` when it should just display the value of `int` that's contained in the json. I have no clue if I'm even on the right track. I have little experience with js, ajax, json, and html, forgive me if this is obvious!
Thanks for any help!

Update: Deleting `JSON.stringify(data)` from the lambda code and just inputting a `1` makes it so the body contains the int and it shows up in the website. This is as expected but I'm just trying to go piece by piece until I break it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to Items here `data.Items`

```
const data = await docClient.scan(param).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: data.Items,
      headers: headers
    }
```

So insted of `data.Items` put `data.Item[0].Payload.int` to receive just `int` value.

Comment: Turn out the "return" is literally json, so just parse/stringify/access properties until eventually reached "int" and send that over. It works now.